# Windows Authentication - How to impersonate a user while developing locally?

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, impersonation

I'm inherited an ASP.NET website project where they have used Windows Authentication. The "admin" account that they are testing are on a separate network, and I need to impersonate that account (there is a table in a database that I currently have that holds the admin account's related contents, so I first need to be able to "logged in" as that user in order to see the contents). I've tried to set the web.config like this:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="admin.user" password="admin.pass" />
```

Where "admin.user" and "admin.pass" are the actual admin's account credentials. However, when I run the site, I received this error message:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

I'm not familiar with Windows Authentication and impersonation so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host it on IIS and then it should work.

Comment: So I need to host the website in IIS instead of run it from Visual Studio? Also, do I need to add "admin.user" account to my local machine? Thanks.